# About the proof using a simple epsilon delta.

Tags: epsilon-delta

## Explanation

I want to prove this equation (1) using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for the function $f(x) = x^2$.

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = a^2 \tag{1}
$$

I've read certain books and I don't agree with some of them.
In that book, $\delta$ was assumed as follows.

$$
\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{(1+2|a|+\epsilon)}
$$

And the continuity can be proved by the following equation.

$$
\begin{aligned}
|f(x) - f(a)| &= |x+a||x-a| \\
&< (|x|+|a|)\delta \\
&< (|a|+\delta + |a|)\delta \\
&= (\delta + 2|a|)\delta < \epsilon
\end{aligned} \tag{2}
$$

## Questions

### 01

The first question is, why can this equation (2) prove that continuity holds?
There is no specific delta value for epsilon.

### 02

The first question is, why does equation (3) below hold?

$$
(\delta + 2|a|)\delta < \epsilon \tag{3}
$$

Comment: What is $f$ here? Is it $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: @babemcnuggets Yes!, I forgot to write it down.
Added definition of function f.

Comment: What kind of "specific figures" for $\delta$ do you want? You can't just set $\delta = 0.001$ (for example) and have a proof, because that value of $\delta$ is good for only some values of $\epsilon,$ and you need a proof that works for _all_ values of $\epsilon.$

Comment: @DavidK I wanted to know the specific delta values for each epsilon. I updated the description of question 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression from the book of $ \delta $ doesn't seem to be correct.

The inequality $ (2)$ does not prove continuity since it does not give the value of $ \delta $.

The inequality $ (3) $ comes from
$$|x-a|<\delta \implies$$
$$-\delta<x-a<\delta \implies$$

$$-|a|-\delta\le a-\delta<x<a+\delta<|a|+\delta \implies$$

$$|x|<|a|+\delta\;\implies$$
$$|x|+|a|<2|a|+\delta \;\implies$$
$$|x^2-a^2|=|x+a||x-a|\le (|x|+|a|)|x-a|$$

$$\le (\delta+2|a|)|x-a|<(\delta+2|a|)\delta$$
So, to realise $|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$, it is sufficient to have

$$(2|a|+\delta)\delta<\epsilon$$
but it does not give $\delta$.

You must add an other condition, like $|x-a|<\color{red}{1}$  .

With this addiitional condition, we will have

$$|x|+|a|<1+2|a|$$
and
$$|x^2-a^2|<(1+2|a|)|x-a|$$
So, if you want that $$|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$$
We will look for $ \delta$ such that

$$|x-a|<\delta\implies (1+2|a|)|x-a|<\epsilon$$
or
$$|x-a|<\delta\implies |x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|)}$$
thus, we can take
$$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}$$
But, there is the additional condition
$$|x-a|<\color{red}{1}$$
So, $\delta $ must be $\le 1$,

$$\delta=\min(\color{red}{1},\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|})$$
This choice, will prove continuity.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the logical development of "−δ<x−a<δ ⟹ −|a|−1a−1<x<a+1<|a|+1"?

Comment: @tan sorry, i edited now.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on the process of obtaining "δ=min(1,(ϵ/1+2|a|)) ?

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments.

Comment: @tan i hope it helped. I you want more ecplanation, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, according to what you reported, the book *does*
give a specific value of $\delta$ for each value of $\epsilon.$
That value is
$$
\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon}.
$$

Notice that $1+2|a|+\epsilon > \epsilon > 0$ and hence this formula for $\delta$
ensures that $0 < \delta < 1.$

For the second question, the book makes several claims for the case
where $\epsilon > 0,$ $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon},$
and $|x-a| < \delta.$
One claim is

$$ |f(x) - f(a)| = |x+a||x-a|. $$

This is true because $m^2 - n^2 = (m+n)(m-n).$
Another claim is

$$ |x+a||x-a| < (|x|+|a|)\delta. $$

This is true because $|x-a| < \delta.$
Another claim is

$$ (|x|+|a|)\delta < (|a|+\delta + |a|)\delta . $$

This is true because $|x| < |a|+\delta.$
Then there is the claim that
$ (|a|+\delta + |a|)\delta = (\delta + 2|a|)\delta, $
which is true by simple rearrangement and combination of terms.
Finally, the book claims that

$$ (\delta + 2|a|)\delta < \epsilon. $$

Plugging in the chosen value of $\delta,$ this is equivalent to the claim that

$$ \left(\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} + 2|a|\right)
      \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon}  < \epsilon. $$

Working this out,

$$ 0 < \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} < 1 $$

and

$$ 0 < \frac{1 + 2|a|}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} < 1, $$

and therefore

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} + 2|a|\right)
      \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} 
  &< \left(1 + 2|a|\right) \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|+\epsilon} \\
  &=  \frac{1 + 2|a|}{1+2|a|+\epsilon}\epsilon \\
  &< \epsilon .
\end{align}

So the claim is true, but what an excessively complicated way this is to do it.

You get a simpler proof if you choose $\delta$ according to the formula in another answer,
$$\delta < \min\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|a|}\right).$$

The value of $\delta$ you get for any $\epsilon$ in this way may be greater than the $\delta$ selected by the book, but it is still small enough to finish the proof.
See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264083) for another proof.